# Maximal flow with multiple sources and sinks

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

How do I find a maximal flow in a network with multiple sources and sinks using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm 'without adding anything to the network'. I know that we could add a supersource node and a supersink node. But there is a question in chapter P of 'Graph Theory - A Problem-Oriented Approach' by Daniel Marcus that asks for a way to do it without adding a supersource node and a supersink node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, use any path from a source to a sink in the residual graph as an augmenting path. To find such a path, start a BFS from all the sources simultaneously: you initialize the BFS queue with all the arcs leaving the sources.

Comment: Does this result in a maximal flow? Is this in any textbook?

Comment: Yes it will give a maximal flow. It is actually the same as having a supersource and a supersink, in the sense that paths in the residual "supergraph" are in an obvious bijection with paths in the original graph, so it is just doing the same. I do not know if there is a textbook explaining the details.